# Multiple openx server single database

Tags: load-balancing, openx

Can I somehow have multiple OpenX servers on amazon cloud and single MySQL on amazon RDS. The main thing which I want to know it that whether can be load balance the OpenX server based on traffic ? Can I separate the MySQL server from the OpenX server. I do not want replication of mysql server but only single mysql server which can be connected from more than one openx server.

Answer (score 2):

From the OpenX documentation:

> The distributed statistics feature allows OpenX to scale by moving some of the load from the central database to web servers. If you are using OpenX with one web server it has to deal with all tasks on one machine. Using multiple web servers allows you to split delivery and admin/maintenance. When using distributed statistics the delivery web servers log raw data (impressions/clicks, etc.) into a local MySQL database and migrate it periodically into the central database. MySQL replication is used to replicate data from the central database into the delivery web servers.
>   [Source: OpenX-Documentation](http://www.openx.com/docs/2.8/adminguide/Distributed%20statistics)

So that means, that there have to be local MySQL-Databeses on every "delivery"-machine. These have mostly to deal with inserts.

For the loadbalancing-part of the question, I am the wrong person to ask, as I am just a Product-Manager with just some technical understanding of the OpenX-Servers we use here.

For more on Replication you might want to [read here in the MySQL-Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html), linked from the OpenX-Docs.

ps.: Sorry, if this answer does not live up totally to the standards of stackoverflow, as this is my first answer ever.

Answer (score 1):

OpenX provide documentation for both single server and multiple server (load balanced) installations here http://www.openx.com/docs/2.8/adminguide/Types%20of%20installation

You can also read about tips and configuration options here http://www.openxtips.com/tag/setup-configuration/page/2/

NOTE: 
If you use a load balancer it might not be clear on which server the settings will be changed (settings file location). It is wise when changing settings to disable the administrator interface on all but one server and use a different domain name which only points to the server with the administrator interface. For example: 'ad.OpenX.com (192.168.1.0)' points to the load balancer which forwards the requests to 'adserver1.OpenX.com (192.168.1.1)' and 'adserver2.OpenX.com (192.168.1.2)'. The administrator interface is disabled on 'ad2.OpenX.com', so you have to use 'adserver1.OpenX.com' to manage the inventory or change configuration settings.